# Standard I/O functions as wrappers around File I/O functions?

Tags: c

I have read somewhere that functions like `scanf` and `printf` are actually wrappers around functions like `fscanf` and `fprintf`, with the FILE pointer set to standard input and standard output respectively.  Is this guaranteed to be true for all implementations of C, or is that a feature of a specific implementation?  I am unable to find any definitive answer to this question, one way or the other.

Comment: Why would it matter if the end result is the same?

Comment: I’m pretty sure it is not guaranteed, but it is pretty much _de facto_ for every implementation I know (specifically, see [Jonathan Leffler’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71880149/2706707).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more likely that they're wrappers around `vfscanf()` and `vfprintf()`, because the 'obvious' implementation is:

```c
int scanf(const char * restrict fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int rv = vfscanf(stdin, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return rv;
}

int printf(const char * restrict fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int rv = vfprintf(stdout, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return rv;
}
```

However, it is certainly true at the calling level that these are equivalent:

```c
printf("The data is %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);
fprintf(stdout, "The data is %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);
```

and so are these:

```c
int rv = scanf("%d %d %d", &i, &j, &k);
int rv = fscanf(stdin, "%d %d %d", &i, &j, &k);
```

This could well be why it is claimed that `scanf()` is a wrapper around `fscanf()`, and `printf()` is a wrapper around `fprintf()`, but when you actually have to get into the nitty-gritty details of how to implement it, you have to write code similar to what I showed to create portable code.  There may be compiler-specific or library-specific shortcuts that a library implementation could take, but it's relatively unlikely that they'd be used in portable code.

I suppose another option is a macro implementation:

```c
#define printf(...) fprintf(stdout, __VA_ARGS__)
#define scanf(...) fscanf(stdin, __VA_ARGS__)
```

However, the implementation must also provide an actual function `printf()` and an actual function `scanf()` to meet the requirements of the standard — see [§7.1.4 Use of library functions](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4).

Comment: Usually `vsnprintf` and the like.

Comment: Why would `printf()` use `vsnprintf()`, @Dúthomhas?

Comment: Why would it use `vfprintf`? IIRC it is just what is at the bottom of glibc’s stack.

Comment: Well, there may be alternatives to `vfprintf()` in a particular implementation, but using `vsnprintf()` requires a buffer and its size, but plain `printf()` isn't constrained by any buffer size.  So using `vsnprintf()` to implement `printf()` would surprise me — whereas using some other internal function instead of `vfprintf()` would not surprise me.  But the code shown is a plausible and reliable way of implementing `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: You are forgetting the commonality of printing to a string. Dumping a string to a file is easy. Making a file that dumps to a string isn’t hard either, but it is more work and it is not part of the standard library. Occam’s Razor applies. But your point stands either way: `v*printf` and the like are typically used underneath to avoid code duplication in libc.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: I am afraid you are mistaken: `printf` is not implemented via `vsnprintf`, at least not in most open source C libraries, but is it a common occurrence to implement `vsnprintf` as a wrapper around `vfprintf` with a tailored `FILE *` or both as wrappers around a common function.  It is indeed possible to implement `printf` as a wrapper around `vsnprintf`, and it would make sense for small strings as you hint, but it would become impractical for larger output strings such as `printf("%2000000000s", "")`.

Comment: Meh, fair enough. I remembered wrong.